# Create SQL linked server with a .net class (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linked-server

I have a program where I used "SQLConnectionStringBuilder" and it was quite easy and handy to do use.

Now, I would like to use the linked server class from Microsoft in order to create a linked server easily. However, I am a bit stuck trying to understand the documentation because it has no examples.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.linkedserver?view=sql-smo-preview

So far I thought it would be something like below:

```
LinkedServer linkedServer = new LinkedServer();
CreateLinkedServer(string server, string database)
{
    linkedServer.Name = "NewLinkedServer";
    linkedServer.DataSource = server;
    linkedServer.Catalog = database;
}
```

At the moment it gives the following error:

> you must set Parent property.

I believe I am missing the authentication mode (and probably something else) to use in order to connect but I've only have seen in the list the "LinkedServerLogins" property which I am not sure how to use.

Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show all errors verbatim.

Comment: Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: 'You must set Parent property.'

Comment: [edit] into your question.